# Windows Server 2008 firewall and ftp

Tags: windows-server-2008, firewall, ftp

I run a script on my server which downloads then uploads via C:\Windows\system32\ftp.exe (The built in windows FTP).
To enable this I have added a firewall exception for the program ftp.exe.

Is this a bad idea, should I be doing something different with the firewall?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks like the right solution to me.

As far as ftp in general, I tend to err on the side of paranoia. FTP is an unsecure protocol. If you want it, there's a free ftp over ssl (FTPS) option available from msft for Server 2008: http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/263/installing-and-configuring-ftp-on-iis-7/

If you do use FTPS, you'll need to take a look at this technet article on configuring the firewall http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd421710(WS.10).aspx.